# How do you write a macro that takes arguments containing paragraphs?

Tags: macros, tex-core, paragraphs, arguments

I'm trying to write a macro that takes arguments containing paragraphs. If you write a normal macro and one of its arguments contains a paragraph, it will break:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\def\mymacro#1{#1}

\mymacro{This

contains a paragraph}

\end{document}
```

This produces an error:

> ```
> Runaway argument?
> {This
> ! Paragraph ended before \mymacro was complete.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \par
> l.15
> ```

So I tried to redefine `\par` for expanding the arguments of the macro, but now it won't stop compiling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\gdef\oldpar{\par}

\def\mymacro{\gdef\par{}\mymacroi}

\def\mymacroi#1{#1\gdef\par{\oldpar}}

\mymacro{foo

bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\long\def` or `\newcommand`.

Comment: I recommend defining a new _environment_ instead of a _command_.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. I was _so sure_ that I had written commands in the past whose arguments could span paragraphs. It makes sense now, it was before I started using \def instead of \newcommnad.

Comment: `\def` is not a latex command, `\newcommand` which, is already allows paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sometimes I need versions of \def. I have no idea how to replicate \edef, \gdef or \xdef with \newcommand (which I believe is \gdef?). What does it even mean for a tex command not to be a latex command?

Comment: latex is written in tex, and tex being a macro expansion language means that all tex primitives are technically available but that doesn't mean that they should be used, especially not in a docuemnt, using in a package code is rather different. "latex" in that sense is the language defined by the latex book.

Comment: The good thing is that \newcommand automatically checks to see if the name has been previously used, and it can also handle one optional argument.  \def is best used when you don't care if it was previously defined or not (e.g. inside a group).  The way \def handles arguments is more adaptable but more difficult to code.  Also, there is no LaTeX for \edef, \gdef or \xdef.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm aware of all of that, but telling people never to use plain Tex commands in an online Q&A called TeX.SX seems a bit weird to me. And it's not that I didn't try to google for an answer, but while it is pretty easy to figure out what \long does when you look for it, it's pretty hard to find why \def + \par crashes.

Comment: What I am saying is to take such advice with a grain of salt.  Personally I mix low level and high level commands all the time, with a preference for whatever requires less typing.  I also try to avoid loading packages I don't need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the time TeX was written, one page of a document would take several minutes to be processed, and syntax highlighting was not a thing, so it was a good thing to have some mechanism to detect if you forgot a `}`. A `\def`, by default, doesn't allow a `\par` token unless you explicitly say it's a `\long\def`:

```
\def\mymacro#1{#1}
```

LaTeX, on the other hand, uses that by default, so if you use proper LaTeX commands (`\def` shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents), `\newcommand` makes a `\long\def` by default. If you want a “short” `\def` then you use `\newcommand*`.

`xparse` returns the short argument default, but lets you define a `\long` macro using the `+` argument modifier:

```
\NewDocumentCommand\mymacro{ m}{#1}% \def
\NewDocumentCommand\mymacro{+m}{#1}% \long\def
```

---

Your second attempt is clever, and it could have worked except for two things.

First is that you are using `\gdef\oldpar{\par}` and then `\gdef\par{\oldpar}`. Once you *expand* `\par` you get `\oldpar` which, when expanded, yields `\par` which, when expanded, yields `\oldpar` which, when expanded, yields `\par` which, when expanded, yields `\oldpar`... Running forever :/

You need to use `\let` (or `\global\let` to have global effect) in this case: `\let\oldpar\par`. This creates an exact copy of `\par` named `\oldpar` which does not depend on what is `\par`.

Second, the runaway argument checking is implemented in a lower level, independent of the definition of `\par`, so this would fail with the same error:

```
\let\par\relax
\def\mymacro#1{#1}
\mymacro{foo

bar}
```

because when TeX sees two `\endlinechar` tokens (which is a space by default) TeX inserts an implicit `\par` token, which raises the `Runaway argument` error. Knowing that, then:

```
\newcount\oldELchar
\oldELchar=\endlinechar
\def\mymacro{\endlinechar=-1\relax\mymacroi}
\def\mymacroi#1{#1\endlinechar=\oldELchar}
\mymacro{foo

bar}
```

won't raise an error, but a new line won't be a space anymore.

Comment: Haha, I was wondering where I went into infinite recursion...

Comment: @sgf You can say, for instance, `\tracingall` before the command you suspect is infinite-looping. You'll get a ton of garbage in the terminal and the log, but it gets easier to find out what is TeX doing.

Comment: I would take a slight difference with the statement "(`\def` shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents)".  Certain service routines a user writes *may* require the special parsing provided by `\def` syntax.  I think it would be better to say "(`\def` should be avoided, where possible)".

Comment: the endlinechar version has to be used with care, for example it also removes the end of line after `\mymacro` (even if there is text following `\mymacro`) not just the one in the argument.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes so when is it impossible to put that in a foo.sty and use `\usepackage{foo}` ?  (note I'm not saying I have never put `\def` in a latex document, just saying it is wrong to do so:-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I agree with you. I hardly ever use `\newcommand`. However, the intent of LaTeX is to hide the `\def`ing thing from the writer, which should just add the necessary `\usepackage` which does what they need. Of course no one follows that strictly, so there are plenty `\def`s around. But one assumes that when a user knows how to use `\def` they should also know the implications of that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why does the end line following the macro is consumed? Shouldn't the `\endlinechar` be restored at that time? (I forgot to emphasize that I was not suggesting that approach :-)

Comment: tex takes a line at a time and inserts the character specified by \endlinechar at the point it grabs the next line at the end of the buffer before tokenizing., so its timing is well defined but er "delicate" :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, I though `\endlinechar` was just a “special `\catcode`” which was also applied when tokenizing. Interesting... Thanks :D

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik no it's a character value rather than a catcode and happens earlier, at the same time white space is stripped from ends of lines, and it adds an un-tokenized character which is then tokenized using the catcode of that character when (if) the end of line is reached.  try the above with `\endlinechar=-1` changed to `\endlinechar=\`X ` and it's easier to see where the X is added.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course you can put it in a style file, but not everyone is a style-file writer.  To me that is a distinction without a difference.  Cordoning off an area of your preamble for service routines is, to me, wholly equivalent to what you suggest.  Further, not all journals accept the use of "private" style files.

Comment: I concur with your sentiment that one should realize the *implications* of using a `\def` in preference to a `\newcommand`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes actually there are benefits to putting it in a package, for example converters to html are almost certainly going to fail on arbitrary low level definitions in the document, but most of them (certainly latexml, tex4ht) can load "matching" relevant definitions for any package loaded so if you have a `mylocaldefs.sty` and decide to make an html version you can make a `mylocaldefs.ht` to save the convertor having to try to convert the definitions. It keeps the actual document separate from the implementation, (almost) always a good thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for that info.  I don't do html conversion, so was unaware of those details.  I agree that, if your source code is going to interact with other people or software, keeping the implementation separate is an even greater idea.

Answer (score 2):

The argument of a macro defined with `\def` does not allow `\par` tokens. Neither it allows blank lines, because they're transformed to `\par` during the phase in which TeX processes text input into tokens. Note that redefining `\par` is useless in this respect, because it's *precisely* the token `\par` that's disallowed, independently of its meaning.

Solution: make your macro `\long`.

```
\long\def\mymacro#1{#1}
```

Better solution:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{#1}
```

because `\newcommand` uses `\long\def` internally. The variant `\newcommand*` instead uses `\def` without the prefix.